# How do I add Time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So my data is `1:30 PM.` I want to have a Data when user selects a time, I want it to add **1hr 30mins** to that and make the data as `1:30 PM - 3:00 PM`. I've been searching for an answer and tried some workarounds but i couldn't get it. BTW the datatype of my Time is `Varchar`, because when I tried using the Time datatype I had some issues on inserting from C# to SQL

Comment: You probably should fix the data type situation first if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--this does a few things
-- 1) converts the time stored as a varchar to the time datatype
-- 2) adds 90 minutes
-- 3) converts the time result back to the varchar datatype

select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(mi, 90, convert(time, '1:30 PM')), 100)


--this will show a final result of "3:00PM"
```

**EDIT:**

The following query will also return a `varchar` with the space between before the AM/PM.

```
select format(dateadd(mi, 90, convert(datetime, '1:30 PM')), 'h:mm tt')
```

The `'h:mm tt'` is written with one "h" so that it will show up as "3:00 PM", instead of "03:00 PM".

**Using Replace:**

This would be how I would use `replace` to get to the goal of "3:00 PM"

```
select replace(replace(convert(varchar(10), dateadd(mi, 90, convert(time, '1:30 PM')), 100), 'P', ' P'), 'A', ' A')
```

Comment: is there a way for me to put space between that 3:00 PM

Comment: sir I'm using sql 2008 which doesn't recognize format as function, so i tried using replace, but it gave me a result of Jan 1 1900 3:00PM

Comment: @JCBorlagdan Apologies, didn't know what version you were on. In that case, change the `convert(datetime, '1:30 PM')` piece back to `convert(time, '1:30 PM')`

Comment: it's my mistake I forgot to mention. hmm i'm getting 15:00:00.0000000 which technically correct but I want to display it as 3:00 PM, i'm reading articles but i couldn't get it

Comment: @JCBorlagdan See my last edit, that should work for ya.

Comment: sorry for my very late reply.. I came up with same query  actually :D but many thanks for the effort and time sir

Answer (score 3):

tested with sql-server 2008

```
 declare @t varchar(25)

    set @t = '1:30 PM'

    --conert a varchar to time
    select CONVERT(time, @t)

    --if you want to add 90 minutes to it

    select DATEADD(minute,90,CONVERT(time, @t))
```

Comment: the output is 13:30:00.0000000 and 15:00:00.0000000

Comment: yes, because it is now a time format.  just do a convert(varchar,DATEADD(minute,90,CONVERT(time, @t)),options)  for a list of options, go here. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/